# CommandText Property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The following code attempts to delete a selected row from a datagridview and update the database.

But it's not updating the database...it's just issuing the error, "CommandText Property has not been initialized." ...any ideas? I assume it's because it's not being bound in the beginning, but at this point I'm clueless and my head is sore.

```
private void deleteRow()
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", "Confirmation", 
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        while (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]);                

        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tradesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tradesTableAdapter.Update(this.tradesDataSet.Trades);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred during the update process: " + ex);
            // Add code to handle error here.
        }

        this.tradesTableAdapter.Fill(this.tradesDataSet.Trades); // refresh table
    }
}
```

Comment: The root cause probably lies outside this code where your Connection and SqlCommand are instantiated and configured. Can you post those into your question?

Comment: I don't use any SQL commands... just dataset and tableadapter...

Comment: Your Update command in data adapter is not set. So it does not know how to updated. Its is generated automatically but sometime designer may mess thing up and delete it from designer code file.

Comment: I think you're right. I did a search in my designer code and "Update" is nowhere to be found. Do I put the following in my designer code somewhere? this.tradesTableAdapter.Update

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my table adapters, datasets, etc... and recreated the entire table. Populated it with new data, and tried to delete a row. It worked... Don't know why, but it works now.

Comment: It works because you now has a command assigned to the UpdateCommand property of the DataAdapter.

Comment: yea, in the DataSet designer, click on the FillBy query and look at the properties window.  You should see places for Select, Update, Insert and Delete queries.  It can auto-populate these, and for the most time its fine, but be aware!